# result.viewname is always string.empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nunit

I cannot seem to return the result.ViewName for use in Nunit tests as it always returns string.empty. I have explicitly set the name of the view inside my controller and would expect the test to pick this up. I have had a hunt around and it seems that I should get the Viewname back if I set it explicitly. Any one got any ideas?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

My test looks like this

```
    [Test]
    public void TestIndexView()
    {
        var controller = new HomeController();
        var result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;
        Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.ViewName);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try cleaning and rebuilding solution? It should work without problems.

Comment: Looks like I had a reference problem with the mvc! Duh

Comment: Post you comment as an answer so I can accept it, Thanks Luk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try cleaning and rebuilding solution? It should work without problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return new View("Index");`.  If this were C the reason why is because of the way you're creating the `View` in `Index()` it is just stored on the stack and goes out of scope (and thus gets collected) when the function ends.  This would cause C to crash, but C# appears to be a little smarter in this regard.

Comment: Really? According to http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-07-cs.aspx it does not mention "new"...

Comment: View() function creates ViewResult.

Comment: Ah, oops.  I was thinking view was a class, not a function.  Fail.